Make Table Query and Linked excel file
I have an Excel file that is updated regularly I.e. Every minute, and I have linked this file to a table in MS Access.  This works great.  However, I cannot index my key unique field, and therefore, I created a make table query to recreate the table.  I can then index my unique field and then set up a relationship to my other tables, and build some queries.
However, my linked table is updating with the refreshed data in Excel (it is not new records, but same records being updated with latest data), but my make table query table is not updating… please can you advise how I can easily also get the correctly indexed table to update from the linked table data?
I hope this is not too stupid a question.
Thanking you in advance for your help.
I have not tried anything, as not been able to.

I do not see any jQuery here so I am removing that tag and adding excel instead

my make table query table is not updating : The make-table query not works? Or you need a mechanism to automatically detect changes in the linked excel file and update the local table?

A make-table query overwrites an existing target table. Thus, replace the query with an update query.

Shahram, the make table query works. I do need a mechanism to automatically detect changes in the linked excel file and update the local table… this would be excellent.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
